# Vue js : Async await with vue js returns observer

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await

Currently I'm trying to get data from api and read it in an array. The problem is 
when I log the data response data from api, it shows the data. I assign the value of variable to data from await. When I `console.log` it shows that the value of variable is obsever. I tried with `async/await`. Installed

```
"babel-plugin-transform-regenerator": "^6.26.0",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0"
```

---

```
const baseUrl = "http://...";
    export default {
      name: "report",
      data() {
        return {
          selected: "",
          categories: []
        };
      },
      created() {},
      methods: {
        async getCategories() {
          this.categories = await axios
            .get(`${baseUrl}/feedback/search`)
            .then(res => {
              return res.data;
            });
        }
      },
      mounted() {
        this.getCategories(); // removed and tried adding this line again
        console.log("cat ", this.categories);
      }
    };
```

This is what I'm getting: `cat -> [__ob__: Observer]`
This method also, seems not to help. What am I doing wrong?

I'm struggling with this problem for hours.. Checked many options in stackoverflow, but none seems to work (or I'm doing smth wrong). I am new in vuejs, I would be really pleased to answers!

Comment: you does nothing wrong (although the async/awaits are useless), `this.categories` is observer created by `vue`

Comment: how can I convert it to json? Can you please help? `JSON.parse(this.categories)` and  `methods: {
    async getCategories() {
      await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/feedback/search`).then(res => {
        console.log("res is ", res);
        this.categories = res.data.json();
        return res.data;
      });
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getCategories();
    console.log("cat ", this.categories);
  }`

Answer (score 1):

You're logging `this.categories` before `this.getCategories()` has resolved, in which case `this.categories` would still be an empty array. Note the `__ob__` property is automatically inserted by Vue and used for reactivity.

You should `await` that method beforehand:

```
async mounted() {
  await this.getCategories();
  console.log("cat ", this.categories);
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/wokrqnoqj5)

Comment: It returns a `cat  Promise {<pending>}` for ` methods: {
    async getCategories() {
    this.categories = axios.get(`${baseUrl}/feedback/search`).then(res => {
        console.log("res is ", res);
       
        return res.data;
      });
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    await this.getCategories();
    console.log("cat ", this.categories);
  }`

Comment: Sounds like you removed `await` when assigning `this.categories`. The only change needed in your original code is to prefix `mounted` with `async`, and then add `await` inside `mounted()`. See [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/wokrqnoqj5)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
const baseUrl = "http://...";
export default {
  name: "report",
  data() {
    return {
      selected: "",
      categories: []
    };
  },
  created() {},
  methods: {
    async imageCategories() {
      this.categories = await axios
        .get(`${baseUrl}/feedback/search`)
        .then(res => {
          return res.data;
        });
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
  await this.getCategories(); // removed and tried adding this line again
    console.log("cat ", this.categories);
  }
};
```

Comment: I thinkt it should be getCategories() not imageCategories() in methods option. Didn;t work with fixing the function name too. I tried this before. But, thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply log after received the data

```
async getCategories() {
   const res = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/feedback/search`)
   const data = await res.data
   console.log('cat ',data)
   this.categories = data
}
```

Comment: Tried this `methods: {
    async getCategories() {
      const response = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/feedback/search`);
      const data = await response.data;
      console.log("data", data);
      this.categories = data;
      console.log("cat ", this.categories);
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    await this.getCategories(); // removed and tried adding this line again
    console.log("cat ", this.categories);
  }'. Didn't solve the problem.` Prints : `data {data: Array(11)}` `cat  {__ob__: Observer}`
`cat  {__ob__: Observer}`

Comment: @Nodirabegimxonoyim isn't the data correctly printed?

Comment: Yes, response from api is printed, but again when I read it is not showing the result. Showing that it is observer instead. Also, I am printing it to see if I'm getting correct data `You can simply log after received the data` beacuse I want to use the data in form

Comment: @Nodirabegimxonoyim can you try `console.log(this.categories.concat([]))`?

Comment: It shows the following erro. `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _this.categories.concat is not a function`. I don;t understand why this is happening. Should update the question with my `.babelrc` and `webpack.config.js`?

Comment: how about `console.log(this.categories.data.concat([]))`

Comment: Hey! You saved my nerves! Thank you! I tried: `methods: {
    async getCategories() {
      const response = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/feedback/search`);
      const data = await response.data;
      console.log("data", data);
      this.categories = data.data.concat([]);
      console.log("cat ", this.categories);
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    await this.getCategories(); // removed and tried adding this line again
    console.log("cat ", this.categories);
  }`. I assigned `.data.concat([])` of response and it shows the result. Also, form is showing data. Thank you so much!